# Where can I download PostgreSQL 8.0 Windows binary files?

Tags: postgresql, windows-installer, binary

I need the PostgreSQL 8.0 binaries for me to recover the data from a crashed server, which has no backup whatsoever. I've looked at the official website link for downloads http://www.postgresql.org/ftp/binary/v8.0.22/, but I couldn't find the binary for Windows. Only for Linux.

I think it was because of something about they only support from version 8.2 and above for Windows. But I'm quite sure the one in the crashed server was installed from a binary version of PostgreSQL 8.0.

Anybody still keep a copy of this binary installer? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It seems the only way to do it is via Cygwin. It's mirrors still have the binaries for version 8.0.x. I will try to install that first. It will be great if anyone still have binary installer or .msi installer from PostgreSQL itself, though :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about 8.0.22, but here is [PostgreSQL 8.0.15](http://www.postgresql.org/ftp/binary/v8.0.15/win32/).

**Update:** The files are gone from the official site and the mirrors.  As of this writing, the files are still available [here](http://mirror.eco.unicas.it/postgres/binary/v8.0.15/win32/).

Comment: Unfortunately, none of the mirrors listed there seem to have the binaries anymore :(

Comment: Wow, really hard to find.  Try http://mirror.eco.unicas.it/postgres/binary/v8.0.15/win32/

Comment: And... downloading them now! Thanks a lot for the help, man! I'm trying to restore the DB next.

Answer (score 0):

You  can do it with mingw as well.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/faqs.FAQ_MINGW.html

Tools for Building Binaries
The native Win32 port requires a 32-bit NT-based Microsoft operating system, like Windows NT 4, Windows 2000/2003, or Windows XP. (NT 4 is no longer supported since version 8.2)  Earlier operating systems do not have sufficient infrastructure. Building the port also requires MinGW and Msys, which can be downloaded from http://www.mingw.org/. MinGW is a Unix-like build environment for Microsoft operating systems. Msys is a collection of unix tools required to run shell scripts like configure.  Neither is required to run the resulting binaries;  they are needed only for creating the binaries.  Work is in progress to support building using Visual C++ in a future version.

Steps For Building Binaries
Download the nightly snapshot tarball from ftp://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/dev or checkout via CVS (you will need bison, flex, and perl installed to build from CVS)
Run configure (you might need to add the --without-zlib argument, depending on whether you have installed zlib on MinGW)
Run make install
Note:  it is suggested that you run psql under CMD.EXE., as the Msys console has buffering issues.

Answer (score 0):

Another location is here: http://www.enterprisedb.com/products/pgdownload.do#windows